# MATCH() failing in Exec VBA - Expected: List Separator or ')'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the worksheetfunction MATCH() in vba.  I'm referencing a listobject:

```
debug.print Application.Match("Austria", qryGeoSubRegions[SubRegionname])
```

but it just returns an error `Expected: List Separator or ')'` , it doesn't seem to like the table column reference.  Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with your column reference. Can you confirm that

```
qryGeoSubRegions[SubRegionname]
```

refers to a a contiguous range of cells containing possible lookup values?

You could test this idea with a simpler definition of the range, like

```
debug.print Application.Match("Austria", Worksheets(1).Columns(1), 0)
```

Comment: Yes it does, it works perfectly in-cell, but in vba doesn't like it. I'm trying to assign the range of the ListObject.ListColumns(1).range, then use that.  It's faffing, but it seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a worksheet reference in vba.  Either change the reference to vba or use Evaluate:

```
 debug.print Application.Match("Austria", Range("qryGeoSubRegions[SubRegionname]"))
```

OR

```
debug.print Activesheet.Evaluate("MATCH(""Austria"", qryGeoSubRegions[SubRegionname])")
```